# BenQ monitor automatically changes brightness based on background colour

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, brightness

Whenever I am doing something that has a dark background, my main monitor automatically dims itself. At first I thought it was dynamic contrast, but it's not turned on. I also tried disabling sensor monitoring service, but to no avail. The problem seems to only happen to whatever monitor I set as my main. So if I set my second monitor as the main one and open up a video with a dark background, only that monitor dims. I've been trying to figure out what's wrong for a few days now, but nothing seems to work. I sent BenQ an email regarding this problem, but all they responded with was an RMA request. If possible, please help.

Specs:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- i5 4690k
- 8 GB RAM
- Asus Z97-A
- Two BenQ GL2460 monitors
- AMD r9 290x
- 1 TB WD HDD
- 120 GB Crucial SSD.

How can I get my monitor brightness to remain constant?

Answer (score 0):

I really enjoy being right on time when someone answers a question so let me see if I can help.

There is a DynamicContrast setting on your monitor.

You need to set it to 0. This will disable it, if it's not set you will be at the will of whatever content is on the screen to "enhance" the experience.

This issue still happens on the newest benq monitors with dark screens.

hope that helps!

Comment: OP states his is not enabled.

Comment: bruh this is three years later, what are you doing

Comment: Oops sorry, I was browsing by tag (and using a Dex station from a distnce), didn't notice it was so dated.

Comment: @Arctiic haha happens to the best of us